# R: help on T only if previous entry is T

Tags: r, time-series

I am writing in R and trying to condition an Exit point base on previous Entry point being "TRUE"

For example:

```
EntryPositions = sscore>=1.25

> EntryPositions
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
   25    26    27    28    29    30    31 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As you can see from the attached image below, the Entry is "TRUE2 on time = 2, 20 and 24
How do i write a code whereby my Exit positions (as sscore is below 0.5) whereby it is conditioned that the previous entry has happened?

See the picture

[image]

I tried writing `ExistPositions=<0.5`

but this is what i get, which is not what i wanted:

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
   25    26    27    28    29    30    31 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

the right result should be exit on t=3, 23 and 25.

Thank you for your help, it would be good if it is in binary form too.

Comment: Could you post sscore? That'd make it easier for us to check.

Comment: Depending on the code, can you say `EntryLagPosit <- c(FALSE, tail (EntryPosition, n = -1))` and therefore `ExitPosition <- EntryLagPosit & (sscore <= 0.5)`?

Comment: Exit == < 0.5 AND `are_entered`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to work with indexes in this case, e.g.

```
entryInd <- which(EntryPositions)
possibExitInd <- which(ExistPositions)
```

Now, you need to pick closest exit for each entry

```
exitInd <- sapply(entryInd, fun(i, x) x[which(x > i)[1]], x=possibExitInd)
```

This should do the job, but note that the function within `sapply` is not very speedy, and can be improved upon.